# Please burninate tag fx-8350?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[fx-8350](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fx-8350) was created [here](https://superuser.com/questions/565489/expected-operating-temperature-for-a-fx-8350-with-stock-cooler)

It's a specific model number so I don't think it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the tag from the question. Waiting for the auto-removal to pick it up. I don't think there's a need to have it manually removed.